# For what manifold is boundary given odd-dimensional projective space?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Take projective real space $\mathbb P_n (\mathbb R)$ of ODD dimension. It is easy to proof that all his Stiefel-Whitney numbers are zero . So according Thom theorem
there must exists manifold $M$ with boundary such that boundary is 
$\partial M= \mathbb P_n (\mathbb R)$. I should like  to see directly such $M$, without using Thom Theorem . For example if $n=1$  evident choice is $M=$ closed disk.
I have no idea in general case. Can some one help please ?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8829/what-manifolds-are-bounded-by-rpodd gives the answer.

Comment: @Jason De Vito: Wonderfull! Thanks very much for very quick answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the equivalent question on mathoverflow: [What manifolds are bounded by RP^odd?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8829/what-manifolds-are-bounded-by-rpodd)

(Since it seems there is a good reason to have the answer recorded as such (and, borrowing from the suggestion [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments)), I'm moving my comment here.  Since all I'm doing it linking to another place, I don't want to gain reputation for this, so I'm making it community wiki.)

However, in an effort to personally gain *something*  from this, I'll provide a link to a similar [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14698/what-manifold-has-mathbbhpodd-as-a-boundary) I asked on MO which still hasn't been answered.  The question is: What manifold has $\mathbb{H}P^{odd}$ as a boundary?  Incidentally, the case of $\mathbb{C}P^{odd}$ is covered in my question.

Comment: If I took the wrong line of action here, please let me know!

Comment: I think that's the right thing to do. I hate when I'm searching unanswered questions and see that some were already answered in comments.